# What is the real size of a Neo4j database?

Tags: database, neo4j

In [this article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-database-growth/) is written how to calculate the size of a Neo4j database.
But the autohor ignores the (large) neostore.transaction.* files.

Using the command `du -hc $NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/graph.db/*store.db*` says "172 Mb" in my case, but the overview in the Neo4j-browser says 1.92GiB.

Which one is the "real" size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of what you called the database size.

The article has right if you considered only the data of the database.

Like you said, the calcul doesn't take in count the `neostore.transaction.*` because it's not your data, but the transaction log of Neo4j  ; it's the same for the indexes.

Comment: If you would compare Neo4j with MySQL and hold a speech, would you say "Yeah, this is my szenario and MySQL need 123,3 MiB, but Neo4j needs 1.81 GiB" or would you ignore the transaction files in that case? It's also possible to disable these logs. So I'm not sure what to do because Neo4j.com says that it's not recommended to do that (disble transaction logs) in production...

Comment: I will ignore the tx log. FYI, MySql also has a tx log ( like every ACID database), and usually when we take the size of a database, we ignore it. But this file is REALLY important for the database operation.

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't really make sence in my case :( I create a new database and use "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM...." to load my data from a .csv file. After that, there is a huge neostore.transaction.db.0 file (17 MB) and completly empty files like neostore.relationshipstore.db & neostore.propertystore.db (0 Bytes each). It seems that the transaction file contains all the graph data. And when I delete that transaction file, the Neo4j browser says that I have "0 nodes and 0 relationships"... I'm so confused..

Comment: When you perform a transaction, every atomic modification are written in the transaction file. Then periodically a background job applies those modifications on the data store (we called it a checkpoint).  You can take a look at the documentation here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/. And like I said SQL database has the same behaviour : https://www.sqlshack.com/beginners-guide-sql-server-transaction-logs/

Comment: Ok, interesting. So if I want the files like neostore.relationshipstore.db & neostore.propertystore.db to be filled by the content of the transaction file, I can set dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=2 hours and wait 2 hours or dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=2 txs and make 2 more random transactions? Or can I execute that background job you mentioned immediately?

Comment: To trigger a checkpoint, just do to clean shutdown of the server (retention policy is different than the checkpoint frequency ...).

Comment: Does not work for me. I have Neo4j Desktop installed and click the "Stop"-icon (this seems to be a clear shutdown), but nothing happens. Still empty files...

Comment: You should read this : https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/checkpointing-and-log-pruning-interactions/ Every 15min a checkpoint is triggered